# How to remove default cakephp css without removing it from default.ctp

Tags: php, css, cakephp, styles, bootstrap-4

I want to update the layout of my pages one by one with bootstrap. Right now the page i am working on uses the cake.generic.css, but I want to remove it for this one page.

How can I go about removing the cake.generic.css from this one page ? If I were to remove it from layouts/defaults.ctp it will mess up the rest of the website.

Comment: Don't import cake.generic.css in layout page. Import it in those pages where it is required. That's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by 2 ways

1.**By using different layout files** -  Use different layout in which that css file not included.you need to create a file in layout folder (for example customlayout.ctp) then you can use this custom layout by

`$this->viewBuilder()->layout('customlayout'); //you can call it in beforeFilter or initialize() method`

2. **By checking current controller and action name**-  In your default layout you can check your current controller and action and can include file only if controller and action is same where you want to include file

**Example**

```
 <?php if(strtolower($this->request->params['controller'])=="controllernameinsmallletters" && strtolower($this->request->params['action'])=="actioninsmallletters") { ?>
        <?= $this->Html->css('cake.generic.css') ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You saved me, thank you!  I was sure I could do something in the controller, but I just couldn't find this!  I will definitely use number 1.

Comment: glad to help you :) .